# vagrant fails to start up in osx mountain lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using Vagrant version 1.1.5 and virtual box 4.2.22. when i do vagrant up, It fails with the following error

Error: The VM failed to remain in the "running" state while attempting to boot. This is normally caused by a misconfiguration or host system incompatibilities. Please open the VirtualBox GUI and attempt to boot the virtual machine manually to get a more informative error message.

I check the virtual box logs, It says /Applications directory is writable by everyone. So I fixed it by removing the write permission for the work for /Applications directory.

But the problem is the permission gets reset almost daily. I have to redo the above the fix daily to use vagrant. Any body know why this is happening or any direction I could take to fix this ?

Regards
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the issue is to do with the permissions - well probably not... that will probably just be a warning.

Try running vagrant in Gui mode to see if you can see any errors in the VM itself.

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html

Comment: I tried with the gui. The result is the same except that it opens a window for a split second and it closes.
I tried to run from virtual box directly, I get this error
`
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
`

also I see this error in virtual box log .. https://gist.github.com/rajofchennai/5763018

Answer (score 0):

First check if you are able to do

```
VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant ssh
```

if not the following solution is most probable.

One of the common error is configuration of ssh key .which one the notice using.

```
VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up
```

There if you see vagrant looping for ssh key.

you can easily fix that using following commands .

```
 vkey() { sudo chown "$*":staff ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key; 
 vkey <new_owner_username>
```

here vkey() is the zsh function.

credits: https://superuser.com/questions/612376/vagrant-vm-fails-to-boot

-let me know if problem still exists

Cheers